# Laravel unread notifications to websocket

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, notifications

I need to push unread notifications to websockets via laravel echo.
Notifications marked as read when user recieved it and close the toast with it, but if he leave or change page w/o closing toast it's still unread.

Can't understand where best way to resend unread notifications?

my variants:

1. on new socket connection do an ajax request for it. (not good way
       always requesting)
2. schedule run resend unreads - it may send even if user still on page
   and looking right now...
3. can't imagine another :)